# Como acumular las cadenas que va produciendo un bucle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la variable **a** dentro de un bucle, y al imprimirla me da unos valores cuando está dentro del bucle y otro cuando está fuera. El trozo de código:

```
for x,y in s3:
    a= ("%s%s" %(x,y))
```

Con un print dentro del bucle obtengo lo siguiente (el **end** solo lo tengo para que me lo imprima en la misma línea):

```
for x,y in s3:
    a= ("%s%s" %(x,y))
    print (a,end="")
```

OUTPUT:

```
QPI0♦QFN1998201QPI1♦QFN1998202QPI2♦QFN1998203QPI3♦QFN1998204QPI4♦QFN1998205
```

Con el print fuera del bucle:

```
for x,y in s3:
    a= ("%s%s" %(x,y))
print (a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
QPI4♦QFN1998205
```

Cómo podría imprimir la variable **a** fuera del bucle obteniendo el mismo output que cuándo está dentro?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ... al salir del bucle, `a` tiene el último valor que tenía dentro.

Comment: Si, quiero que al salir del bucle tenga todos los valores, no el último.

Comment: ¿ Entiendo que no sabes usar listas ?

Comment: Si, pero quería saber si existe otro método.

Comment: Pues depende ... un diccionario, una cadena que concatene los resultados, una clase a medida, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu bucle reasigna la misma variable en cada iteración, por lo que se sobreescriben los valores previos y al salir del bucle tendrá sólo el último valor.

Lo que quieres hacer es, en lugar de sobreescribir la variable, ir *aumentándola* por así decir, para que contenga lo que había antes más lo nuevo de cada iteración.

Esto puedes lograrlo de forma sencilla con el operador `+=` para concatenar cadenas:

```
a = ""           # Comienza siendo una cadena vacia
for x,y in s3:
    a +=  ("%s%s" %(x,y))  # Le añades la cadena nueva a la que había
```

Observa que he puesto `+=` en vez de `=`, y eso hace que se *añada*.

Esto funcionará, pero es **ineficiente** debido a que en Python las cadenas son inmutables. Esto quiere decir que realmente no puedes añadir algo a una cadena ya existente, y por tanto lo que Python hace al llegar a la línea que tiene el`+=` es **crear una cadena nueva** (que contiene lo que había antes en `a` más lo que le hayas añadido), descartar la cadena vieja (la que había antes en `a`) y reasignar `a` para que apunte a la nueva cadena ampliada en vez de la previa.

Debido a esta constante creación y destrucción de cadenas en cada iteración del bucle, la solución no es la más eficiente. Esto no tiene mayor importancia si el bucle se va a repetir solo una decena de veces, pero si son cientos o miles puede ser interesante cambiar el enfoque.

Una solución más eficiente es hacer que `a` sea una lista en lugar de una cadena:

```
lista = []
for x,y in s3:
    lista.append("%s%s" %(x,y))
```

Las listas sí son **mutables** y por tanto sí que estamos añadiendo un nuevo elemento a la lista cada vez que iteramos (en vez de estar creando listas nuevas ampliadas y destruyendo las viejas, como ocurría con las cadenas).

Al salir del bucle `lista` contendrá una lista de cadenas. Si lo que quieres es una sola cadena que concatene todo, puedes convertir la lista obtenida en una cadena, mediante el método `.join()` que es también muy eficiente:

```
a = "".join(lista)
```